# React Native (Android): Run inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native

React Native provides an easy way to load JS inside an Activity. I've been trying to do the same inside a fragment. I copied most of the code from ReactActivity class and create a ReactFragment class. I'm still in the middle of figuring this out but I wanted to know if this is even possible. If it's possible what is the easiest way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is very much possible. Just return ReactRootView instance on onCreateView. Route all relevant Activity events to the fragment like onBackPressed etc and it'll work predictably.